# REST Api for get all document libraries who has full control of current user SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, rest

I want to get all the document libraries in which current user has full control using rest api.

it seems that we can check using [effectiveBasePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245395.aspx).

I have used below script :

```
 function GetModifiedDoclib() {
  var executor;
  var appwebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
  executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appwebUrl);
  executor.executeAsync({
    url: appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?@target='" + hostwebUrl + "'&$select=Title,effectiveBasePermissions&$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101&$orderby=LastItemModifiedDate desc",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
    success: function (data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
    },
    error: errorListHandlerXD
 });
}
```

i have make one document library(TestDoc) and havent access of current user.another one document library(Documents) has full control.

my API Output look like :

```
 {"d":{"results":
  [{ EffectiveBasePermissions":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.BasePermissions"},
     "High":"2147483647","Low":"4294967295"},
     "Title":"Documents"},

   {"EffectiveBasePermissions":
    {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.BasePermissions"},"High":"16","Low":"134283264"},
    "Title":"TestDc"}]}}
```

**My doubt : what are value of High and low indicated in output and how can i know user have full control to document library?**

Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is link of Permission mark with value :

http://www.dctmcontent.com/sharepoint/Articles/Permissions%20and%20Mask%20Values.aspx

http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2011/10/23/list-of-sharepoint-base-permissions-with-their-hex-and-decimal-values/

I am not found any solution using REST API but i have accomplish my requirement using Client object model.

```
function GetModifieldDocLib_Privilege() {

 hostwebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
 appwebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

 context = new SP.ClientContext(appwebUrl);
 factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appwebUrl);
 context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
 appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostwebUrl);
 var oWebsite = appContextSite.get_web();
 var collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
 this.listInfoArray = context.loadQuery(collList, 'Include(Id,Title,EffectiveBasePermissions,BaseTemplate)');

 //Execute the query with all the previous 
 //  options and parameters
 context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, GetAllDocLibWithPrivilege),
     Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
  );
}

function GetAllDocLibWithPrivilege() {

for (var i = 0; i < this.listInfoArray.length; i++) {
    var oList = this.listInfoArray[i];

    if (oList.get_baseTemplate() == 101) {
        var perms = oList.get_effectiveBasePermissions();
        if (perms.has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)) {
            // get documentlibraries object whose Current-user has Edit Permission. 
        }
    }

}
```

Hope its helps!!